# Python BS4 scraping: AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I want to scrape the text of each `li` in `ul` with `class="academicsList"` from the following page:

https://www.eduvision.edu.pk/institutions-detail.php?city=51I&institute=3149_federal-urdu-university-of-arts-science-technology-islamabad

I am getting the error: `navigateable string has no attribute text`. What is causing this problem and how can I resolve it?

Here is my code

```
import requests  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
from fake_useragent  
import  UserAgent  

ua = UserAgent()  
header = {'user-agent':ua.chrome}  
response = requests.get('https://www.eduvision.edu.pk/institutions-detail.php?city=51I&institute=3149_federal-urdu-university-of-arts-science-technology-islamabad',headers=header)  

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')  
disciplines = soup.findAll("ul", {"class": "academicsList"})  
for d in disciplines:  
   for li in d:  
    print(li.text)  
    print("...............")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! 
You are trying to iterate the ul tag you found. But you are supposed to iterate the li tags. For that you need to add `.findAll('li')` in d. Like,

```
for d in disciplines:
   for li in d.findAll('li'):
    print(li.text)
    print("...............")
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!